# NestJS Websocket Gateway: using namespaces with the WS adapter

Tags: websocket, nestjs, ws, nestjs-gateways

I am working on implementing a Websocket gateway in NestJS 7, as shown [in the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/gateways#overview).  I use the WS adapter.

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule);
app.useWebSocketAdapter(new WsAdapter(app));
```

The problem I have is that the gateway accepts the connection regardless of the url.  So for instance, If I define my gateway like so:

```
@WebSocketGateway(8080, {namespace: '/v3'}
export class MyGateway {}
```

Then this gateway's `handleConnection` is triggered regardless of the path the client requests:

```
ws://localhost:8080/some-other-path
```

This unfortunately means that all clients are connecting to every gateway. Is the namespace option only available for the socket.io adapter?

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the `path` option:

```js
@WebSocketGateway(8080, {path: '/v3'}
```

Then you can connect with:

```js
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/v3');
```

Platform `ws` doesn't support namespaces. It's a feature of `socket.io`.

Reference: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/4968#issuecomment-772494179